# Calling stored procedures on Oracle throws ORA-06550 exception

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have written a simple test using a jdbc connection and I am trying to understand the failure and possible incorrect Oracle syntax. From my understanding, this should work and searching the internet for a couple hours didn't turn up much to refute this.

Simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE printHelloWorld 
    (in_param_one IN VARCHAR2, out_param_one OUT VARCHAR2) 
    AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS 
BEGIN 
    out_param_one := 'Hello World'; 
END;
```

Test1:

```java
@Test
public void testOracleStoredProcedureWithIndexes() throws SQLException {
    ...
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, props);

    java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("BEGIN printHelloWorld(in_param_one => ?, out_param_one => ?); END;");

    ((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleCallableStatement)cstmt).setString(1, "Test");
    ((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleCallableStatement)cstmt).registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

    ((java.sql.PreparedStatement)cstmt).execute();
    ...
}
```

Test2:

```java
@Test
public void testOracleStoredProcedureWithNamedParameters() throws SQLException {
    ...
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, props);

    java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("BEGIN printHelloWorld(in_param_one => ?, out_param_one => ?); END;");

    ((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleCallableStatement)cstmt).setString("in_param_one", "Test");
    ((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleCallableStatement)cstmt).registerOutParameter("out_param_one", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

    ((java.sql.PreparedStatement)cstmt).execute();
}
```

Running these two tests, "Test1" passes and "Test2" fails. The failure I get from "Test2" is the following:

```
Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 55, Sql = BEGIN procPrintHelloWorld2(in_param_one => IN_PARAM_ONE=>:0, out_param_one => OUT_PARAM_ONE=>:1); END;, OriginalSql = BEGIN procPrintHelloWorld2(in_param_one => ?, out_param_one => ?); END;, Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 1, column 56:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
ORA-06550: line 1, column 92:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
```

I read somewhere that I shouldn't use the ":VAR" syntax, but changing to that does get this working... can anyone more familiar with Oracle point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you see this in your output?

```
procPrintHelloWorld2(in_param_one => IN_PARAM_ONE=>:0, out_param_one => OUT_PARAM_ONE=>:1)
```

It's doubling your named parameters, taking the `?` in your raw SQL and replacing it with `IN_PARAM_ONE=>:0` to get `in_param_one => IN_PARAM_ONE=>:0`.

If you remove those from your SQL string, I think it should work fine either way.

```
java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("BEGIN printHelloWorld(?, ?); END;");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This does get it working... but why is it "doubling your named parameters"? I can already get this test working using **"BEGIN printHelloWorld(:in_param_one, :out_param_one); END;"** syntax. However, I want to know why it doesn't work the way I am writing it.

Comment: If you use indexed parameters, it replaces the first `?` in the SQL string with "Test", so your SQL ends up as `in_param_one => 'Test'` and it works fine. If you use named parameters, it replaces the first `?` with `IN_PARAM_ONE=>:0`, but you've already got `in_param_one =>` in your SQL, so now it's there twice, which is incorrect.

Comment: You are describing WHY the SQL the Oracle jdbc driver constructs is incorrect. I agree that **"in_param_one => IN_PARAM_ONE=>:0"** is incorrect, but I am not constructing this SQL. **"BEGIN printHelloWorld(?, ?); END;"** does not contain any named parameters in it! This is not a fix for the issue. You cannot set named parameters on the statement and have to rely on supplying them in a specific order!

Comment: If you don't want to set your named parameters in a particular order, then don't include them in your SQL string. `"BEGIN printHelloWorld(?, ?); END;"` doesn't contain any named parameters, UNTIL you call `.setString("in_param_one", "Test")`. Calling that function will replace the first `?` with `in_param_one => 'Test'`

Comment: What if I do want to set my named parameters in a particular order?